# Can I register Laravel Auth::routes() under a prefix group?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

Hi I'm working with Laravel 5.3 and I notice that the default Auth routes are registered using `Auth::routes();`. Is it possible to encapsulate these routes under a prefix group? Eg:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Auth::routes();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have. I get a NotFoundHttpException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes You can use it but to make sure now you should prefix your url with admin

e.g
If previously you access your url like http://localhost/auth/login

Now you should prefix your url with admin before auth like below 
http://localhost/admin/auth/login

Issue is in your middleware you use auth middleware

Go to App/http/Middleware/Authenicate.php and there go to handle mathod in a class.
There you see `return redirect()->guest('auth/login');` please replace it with

```
return redirect()->guest('admin/auth/login')
```

Comment: I get this part. How do I make my `auth` middleware redirect me to `/auth/login`.

Comment: you prefix your auth/login routes in admin how can u get to /auth/login ?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.3, it has no `Authenticate.php` in middleware's folder.

Comment: go to app/Exceptions/Handler.php there is a method unauthenticated
there you find a redirect()->guest('login'); replace it with return redirect()->guest('admin/auth/login')

Comment: for further explanation check that link http://laravel.io/forum/08-23-2016-laravel-53-auth-middleware-redirect-guests

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

`Auth::routes()` is just a wrapper method around normal route registering. 
You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/98a18ddd231a31996db537439147b38b495cce89/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L287).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with no restrictions.

Comment: I am trying to access a route with uri `/admin

Comment: Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
 Auth::routes();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web'], function(){
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){

     Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');

 });
});

Comment: @TaeKwonDev 
`Auth::routes();` haven't `/` route. You can try in as `/admin/login`

Comment: Solution for `/admin` route
`Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/', function (){
        return view('welcome');
    });
});`

Comment: please have a look at the code I posted in the answers section to see my actual problem.